# Is it possible to Modify a Form's Properties from another Class

Tags: c#, forms, opacity

Is there a way to modify the properties of a Form from a separate class in a C# project? Specifically what I'm trying to accomplish with this is to be able to add fading capabilities to several Forms without having to re-define the method and loop for each class. Instead, I would like to place this method, which is called `FadeInWindow()`, in a separate class named `SharedMemory` and make it accessible to all Forms for the sake of simplicity.

So that I wouldn't have to construct the class in each Form to have access to the contents of `SharedMemory`, I declared its contents with the `static` modifier.

Here's my fade loop method, located in the `SharedMemory` class:

```
public static void FadeInWindow(Form form, double opacity)
{
     for (double i = 0; i < opacity; opacity += 0.05)
     {
          form.Opacity = i;
          form.Refresh();
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
     }
}
```

I plugged the Form into the method using the `this` keyword. The `opacity` argument defines the maximum limit of the Form's theoretical opacity level. The `for` loop alone worked fine when placed in the Form rather than in `SharedMemory`.

Is there a way around this predicament?

Comment: `i` is always 0, while `opacity` grows infinitely - not sure that's what you wanted.

Comment: check the value of i

Comment: @GrantWinney, I called the method in the Form's Load event, using `SharedMemory.FadeInWindow(this, 80)`.

Answer (score 3):

Two points:

Firstly, you're not incrementing the value you've defined in your for loop. You define the opacity of the Form passed to your method as i, but your increment portion is opacity += 0.05. Your for loop will never end, and the opacity of the form passed to FadeInWindow will never vary. I think if you fix this problem, you'll find your form is updated as you desired.

Secondly, you shouldn't be using doubles as your counter in your for loop. This won't end up causing a problem in this exact case, but it's good to not get in the habit of using them at all. An example of where this can fail you is the following:

```
for (double i = 0; i <= 1.0; i += 0.1) { }
```

Depending on how any specific implementation rounds floating points, this could either execute 9 times or 10 times. (Hint - according to my link below, this only executes 9 times in VS2013, so this is directly relevant.) Floating-point arithmetic isn't anywhere near as predictable as integer addition (which is totally predictable within the minimum and maximum bounds of the type). Rather, if you want to get a multiple of 0.05, you should do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    double currentOpacity = (double)i * 0.05;
}
```

This will always execute exactly 10 times.

Smarter men than I explain the issue [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FLP30-C.+Do+not+use+floating-point+variables+as+loop+counters).